# Inductance of a practical relay

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, electromagnetism

I would like to design an SMPS to feed an electronic circuit that includes a relay. To study the stability of my SMSP I need to model the relay, but when I go through many relays datasheets, they do not include the value of the inductance, but they only talk about the nominal voltage and the coil resistance.

What about the coil inductance? Why don't manufacturers include the inductance?

Comment: Designers actually do think about their relays. So they are managed designs and therefore you can usually compute it from the datasheet. (If they were designed by random hobbyists, the following rule wouldn't work well.) In general, just multiply the specified release time by the coil resistance to get the inductance. Use SI units, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coil inductance is generally not important. In the case of your SMPS the inductance will result in a more gradual increase in current when the relay is connected than a resistor of the same value as the coil's resistance would.

The reason to care about inductance is generally not about switch-on but about switch off when you need to have snubbers fitted to prevent inductive kickback affecting the supply.

Also, I would expect that the inductance will change when the armature closes as the magnetic circuit's reluctance will be reduced.

---

That got me interested. I had no idea what the inductance of a relay would be so I measured one using my EZM328 V1.10 component tester. (These are amazing little devices and are available for about €10.)

[image]

*Photo 1: Relay, Finder Type 40.51, 24 V coil. Note the open armature arm (1). Not visible is the core running through the coil and the steel fixed part of the armature running up to the hinge.*

[image]

*Photo 2. The test setup.*

As can be seen in Photo 2 the results are R = 871 Ω and L = 3 H.

For the second test I held the armature closed by hand. What do you think the inductance reading would be with the armature closed? (Hover over the spoiler to see.)

> Answer: 8 H. This is a gain of 166%!

Comment: You could have just computed it. In general, multiply the release time by the coil resistance to get the inductance. The datasheet says \$900\:\Omega\$ and \$3\:\text{ms}\$. Es gibt \$2.7\:\text{H}\$. Which is about what you found with that nifty tester.

Comment: That's news to me, thanks, @Jonk. I've never thought of it as \$ \tau = \frac L R \$ - probably because we're going open-circuit, arcing, etc. Hmmm ... thinking ...