# Flyback diodes instead of a resistor in series with a capacitor in parallel with the inductor

Tags: capacitor, diodes, circuit-design, flyback, snubber

Why do people use flyback diodes instead of a resistor in series with a capacitor in parallel with the inductor? Wouldn't it be just as good? It would also have the benefit of working with motors that rotate in both directions.
Are there any drawbacks at all?

Comment: Do a simulation and see what the resultant voltage spike will be. I think you'll be surprised. Compare that with the maximum voltage rating of your transistor. I've given some inductance values for a 24 V relay in [another post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487352/inductance-of-a-practical-relay/487353#487353). Use those for starters.

Comment: What inductor? Relays? Motors? SMPS? Filters? And what applications, if relays or solenoids or motors, is there PWM used or not?

Answer (score 1):

Inductors are inherently zero-current turn-on devices. So, when the voltage is applied to them, the initial current is zero.

When an R-C snubber is applied to a coil, the initial current will be as-if the capacitor was shorted, and R was applied directly across the coil. So, zero-current turn-on is lost.

The benefits of a snubber over a simple diode are mostly switching speed, and the where the energy is dissipated: in the snubber resistor, or in the coil itself. Choosing one over the other is a trade-off, so no "one solution fits all".

Instead of a plain diode, back-to-back Zener diodes can be used, speeding up the turn-off. The zero-current turn-on is still retained that way.

Zero-current turn-on is especially important when mechanical contacts switch relay coils, as is the case when e.g. a switch, pushbutton, or another relay contact is used to turn the coil on. Contact life is significantly shortened when turning on the resistive load of the snubber vs. an inductive load of the coil itself.

The zero current turn-on of inductive loads is a reasonable approximation when the coils are physically small, e.g. small-signal relays and such. Large iron-cored inductors have big inrush magnetization current spikes, and there's no benefit to *not* using snubbers with those.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but much more power is wasted. Your resistor burns up the stored energy in the LC system. The resistor is usually chosen to minimize ringing. When frequency is very low like a relay operating occasionally the power burn is occasional so average power loss is low.

Comment: I was thinking of DC motors where the capacitor would open-circuit the resistor during motor operation. But yeah, i see how with a brushless motor it would waste power.

Comment: The resistor burns the same amount of energy as the diode. Both cases waste the same amount of energy.

Comment: @Andyaka .Yes but the inducter is big and the resister is often small,

Comment: It is confusing to say that *much more power is wasted*. More power is *dissipated* (over a shorter period) but the same energy is wasted.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why a diode is used to "catch" or "clamp" the voltage spike instead of a resistor is because the voltage across the diode is limited to around 0.5 - 1V, so the voltage at the drain of the MOSFET (assuming you are using a low side NMOS) would be Vsup + Vd.

In case of a resistor, the inductor will push a current through the resistor which results in a drop of IR across it. So the resulting drain voltage would be Vsup + IR. For large values R (your R would have to be large, otherwise it would waste power during the on time of the switch as well), Vsup + IR would be so large that it could kill the MOSFET.

If you are turning the inductive load on and off very infrequently, you could probably get away with an RC snubber, but if you are PWMing the inductive load, then you are better off using a diode.