# What is the largest electrical connector in the world?

Tags: connector

I know there are some pretty big ones for undersea cables (as seen below and described [here](https://www.gizmodo.com.au/2014/09/the-giant-power-plug-is-used-for-floating-wind-turbines/)), but what else is out there?

The MacArtney 11kV, 400A wet mate connector:

[image: MacArtney 11kV 400A wet mate connector via]

Answer (score 12):

There are also some pretty large busbars. The connection here is done with 14 bolts the size of a man's thumb.

[image]

Comment: Good one....... I had once monitored a steel/zirc/steel  Diffusion welder for nukes. The conduct was solid copper over 12" diameter thru conductive grease bearings to a solid copper flywheel conductors on inside and outside of the 6" tubing. Current was  up to 100kA 4V and was water cooled with sparks flying everywhere.  The Kelvin shunt was 2 screws on the solid copper arm.

Comment: Picture includes a man's thumb for convenient reference.

Answer (score 6):

electric arc furnace eletrodes - tens of thousands of amps.

there are also ship power plugs now for electric supply : [shore power Hamburg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjV_Pgb8lj8)

Comment: I wonder how big the plugs for experimental naval railguns are

Comment: The connector in that video is 2-4 times larger than the one in OP's image!

Answer (score 4):

### A message for those not understanding the first part of this answer

A connector, on the face of it, connects electricity to a load but, in the detail of that connection, are EM waves. In simple terms we call it electricity but in reality there is an electromagnetic wave; that is what is being passed from A to B. At the instant the "connection" is made electric fields and magnetic fields travel to the load.

Now, at low frequencies, the electricity appears to "stop" at the end of the unconnected connector and, for many practical reasons, that's all EEs need to worry or care about but, for many types of connector, if the frequency was much increased we would see electric and magnetic fields forming at the end and, being transmitted into space.

This means that virtually any connector (**especially larger ones**) act like antennas. So, connectors allow the passage of EM waves and they are capable of picking up EM waves and, the bigger they are the more likely that they'll pick up EM waves of lower frequencies.

So, for the down-voters who might suggest that I might be being cynical or "excessively playful", let me remind them that I was the first person to register a close vote and, my reason was that the question attracted opinions AND that it was ill-formed in that it didn't define what was meant by a "connection" (See Solar Mike's accurate comments below this answer).

In short, a connector allows the passage of EM waves and an antenna does the same. The difference is that a connector (and its associated cabling) tries to physically restrict that EM wave to the medium it "inter-connects" whereas, an antenna "connects" an EM wave of one impedance (defined by the feed cable) to an impedance defined by something else.

> *What is the largest electrical connector in the world?*

### A connection to an electric field

China's 500 metre diameter Aperture Spherical Radio Telescope is the biggest connector that I'm aware of. Here's a link to it: [Link](https://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2019-09/caos-cse090919.php#:%7E:text=9%2DSep%2D2019-,China%20Sky%20Eye%2C%20the%20world%27s%20largest%20single%2Ddish%20radio,telescope%2C%20is%20now%20fully%20operational&text=China%27s%20Five%2Dhundred%2Dmeter%20Aperture,world%27s%20most%20sensitive%20listening%20device.)

[image]

Yes, it connects to EM transmissions from space hence, it is a connector. It receives power hence it's a connector. It receives an electric field and it does so intentionally hence it's a connector.

---

### Electric Trains

Another type of large electrical connector is the overhead wire used to connect electricity to the pantograph of an electric train. The return connection is via the track system and the connection is continuous for many hundreds of miles

[image]

The third and fourth rail are other variants. Are these connectors? Sure they are. Are they big? They provide a sliding connection capable of passing megawatts of power to a locomotive for hundreds of miles.

### Electric fencing

These are used to prevent wildlife and farm animals crossing a boundary. The earth is the "return" wire and the animal will receive a "jolt" by virtue that they are "earthed" via their feet and they come into contact with the "wire". The longest one I could find was in Australia [as reported by the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-australia-44235185): -

[image]

It's 44 km long. Is it a connector? Sure it is.

Comment: I can't see the tiny conductor. and here I can see the kid lifting the Rhino connector https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz2VU.jpg

Comment: Wow, that's one powerful kid.

Comment: Similar question: [What is the largest inductance value ever attained (in Henry's)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303320/what-is-the-largest-inductance-value-ever-attainedin-henries/303328#303328)

Comment: In the broadest possible sense you may be correct, but how do you draw the line between this apparatus and something using VLBI, like the event horizon telescope with has an effective aperture of ~Earth's diameter.

Comment: @alessandro I'll leave that to you as it's your question and you have to choice to accept this answer or anyone else's answer. You can draw the line wherever you want. It's your call.

Comment: @alessandro your question needs to define the limits of what you mean by connection.

Comment: @Solar Mike What I was referring with this question was what this article is about: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_connector

Comment: Honestly I anticipated some confusion about what largest meant (contact area, physical size, amperage, etc) not about what an electrical connector is.

Comment: @alessandro then you should have been more precise with your question.

Comment: @Solar Mike I did give an example of the sort of device I was looking for.

Comment: So a connection between two points, not limited to a metal connction so an infra-red connection or microwave connection is valid. Good answers come from good questions...

Comment: @alessandro so you want a disconnectable join that is designed to be made and broken at least N times in its service life, and either doesn't need tooling, or the tooling required is to retain the two sides together (as opposed to join**t**ing the conductors.)   Also need to state if you want electrical power or electrical data.  And are you restricting to AC or DC, or something else ?

Comment: @Andyaka This is a great answer, with several different boxes being thought outside of at the same time!    I'd be tempted to split and post three separate answers, so that each one can get its own up/down votes.  ie, I do think the train and fence are spot-on but the dish not so much because (say) its wireless, so might upvote anyway or might not, or may even downvote because of a perceived mistake.   (that's an example, I upvoted of course)

Comment: Are you sure those overhead wires above the train are continuous for 100's of miles, and not broken up into smaller sections? Those wires don't look big enough to carry 1000's of A needed to deliver megawatts of power (assuming they're too close to the ground to be at more than 1 kV or so). Certainly not 1000's of A for 100's of miles.

Comment: @ThePhoton in principle they could be that long (but need fairly regular substation feeds) and they are usually carrying 25 kV in the UK hence, a megawatt would require 40 amps. Locomotives are around 2 MW.

Comment: @Criggie, the example shown in the question appears to require a crane to position the flexible cable end of the connector set. The mating end seems to include a fixture used to align and bring the connector halves together. That seems to imply the inclusion of connections that require tooling to connect or disconnect.

Comment: I've removed a comment . The message was OK enough but made it's point slightly too bluntly.

Comment: I didn't know there was a zenith telescope larger than the one at the Arecibo Observatory! Neat.

Comment: Telescopes and antennas are most definitely not connectors. I think train wires fit the definition, however. I'm still on the fence about your last example.

Comment: If radio telescopes count as connectors (which they don't) then so do ELF antennas. Wikipedia gives an example of one which is 23km long.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote @user253751