# Where to find huge solenoid inductors (~25 H) or cheap magnet wire?

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism, wire, coil, energy-harvesting

I am on an energy harvesting project, and it would require a 25 H solenoid inductor (width 0.3 mm max).

The only issue is that I am completly unable to find any inductors of that size on the internet. I then turned to making it myself, but seeing that the required magnet wire would cost me over $100, I had to find another way to make that inductor.

Do you think I could salvage it from somewhere? Or I could buy it somewhere? Or (but I doubt it) find a cheaper wire?

Comment: Site rule: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.*

Comment: width?  i understand length bore and diameter, what is width?

Comment: how much current?

Comment: see also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/303320/26376

Comment: Look into the Military and industrial surplus markets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A microwave oven transformer (MOT) will get you into that ballpark, with a bit of work to install an airgap.

Measuring one I have here, it has a pole face area of 35 mm x 70 mm, which is about 2.5m m2. If you gapped it to a total of 1 mm, so 0.5 mm packing on both the centre and return legs (5 sheets of printer paper thick), then you could calculate the expected AL thus, assuming all the reluctance is in the air-gap, and AL = flux linkage per ampere turn.

H for 1 ampere turn = 1/1m = 1k.
So the B field is 4pi.10-7 x 1k = 4pi.10-4
So the flux is B*area = pi uH
As a MOT typically has 2400 turns on the secondary, N^2 = 5.8M
so the final secondary inductance is 5.8pi = 18 H

That's within spitting distance of your required 25 H. All you need to do is reduce the gap a little from the one I've assumed.

What's the maximum current to stay well below saturation? Assume Bmax of 1 T. Hmax = Bmax/u0 = 800k. So with 2400 turns, and a 1 mm path length, that's a very reasonable Imax of 0.3 A.

As the core is built with the absolutely lowest grade iron possible (for shaving pennies from the finished cost), the core losses will be high, and will almost certainly escalate rapidly above mains frequencies. But, from the right sources, the cost is zero, plus a bit of elbow grease to saw through the welds to install the airgap.

As Marcus has commented, the resistance is not going to be zero! My one measures just under 200 Ω.

Now given those results, you might want to specify some other important parameters of the inductor, like operating frequency, losses, and Imax (and maybe weight).

There are other cheap/free sources of low frequency inductors out there. As LEDs are replacing fluorescent tubes in industrial lighting, you might be able to find a skipfull of luminaires somewhere. The inductors from those are usually in the few H ballpark, so you would need several in series to reach your goal.

You could use an ungapped transformer, they are much more readily available than gapped inductors, but the energy storage is usually pathetic, characterised by a very low Imax.

Comment: i wonder about the real part of the impedance. but this is a nice quick rough way to get an idea! kudos.

Answer (score 1):

The Henries is not the problem, but the saturation is.

Take a small mains frequency transformer and put both windings in series. That will likely give you many Henries of inductance.